# ASP.NET 4.5 data binding model SelectMethod throw error

Tags: c#, gridview, model, asp.net-4.5, selectmethod

I confused with this new pattern. Everything is looking simple when you are reading tutorial. But the simplest task I cannot complete - bind data model to GridView.
Here is GridView code:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvIlves" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" ItemType="GuideOnline_1_.Models.xTourist"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Kod" CssClass="table table-striped tablesorter"
                ClientIDMode="Static" PageSize="50" SelectMethod="SelectArrival" UpdateMethod="UpdateArrival">
```

And SelectMethod here:

```
public IQueryable<GuideOnline_1_.Models.xTourist> SelectArrival()
        {
            var now = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-3);
            IQueryable<GuideOnline_1_.Models.xTourist> arrivals = _db.xTourist;
            arrivals = arrivals.Where(p => p.Ответственный !=null).Where(p => p.Номер == null).Where(p => p.Датапр >= now);
            return arrivals;
        }
```

This look simple and smooth, but I got error:
**When the DataBoundControl has paging enabled, either the SelectMethod should return an IQueryable or should have all these mandatory parameters : int startRowIndex, int maximumRows, out int totalRowCount**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stupid mistake. I just mention wrong table name in ItemType.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvIlves" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" ItemType="WebApplication1.Tourist"
            AutoGenerateColumns="True" DataKeyNames="Kod" CssClass="table table-striped tablesorter"
            ClientIDMode="Static" PageSize="50" SelectMethod="SelectArrival"></asp:GridView>
```

Code:

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    public IQueryable<Tourist> SelectArrival()
    {
        return new EnumerableQuery<Tourist>(new List<Tourist>
        {
            new Tourist{ Kod = "1", Name = "Joe", Age = "35"},
            new Tourist{ Kod = "2", Name = "Cliff", Age = "45"},
            new Tourist{ Kod = "3", Name = "Dan", Age = "32"},
        });
    }
}

public class Tourist
{
    public string Kod { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but still not working. Will it help if I say that Model ws built with DB first?

Comment: You could try and do `return arrivals.ToList()`, but I don't think that is the answer. Have you tried setting `AllowPaging="false"`, just to see if it works or if you get another exception?

Comment: Yes, ToList is not answer. I did tried to change to be AllowPaging="false", but there is another error saying about my SelectMethod not return IQueryable.